# Trying to get a cookie value which I set on ARCGIS online but not getting any value back?

Tags: cookies, arcgis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I am trying to set a cookie in ESRI Arcgis online using ESRI runtime SDK for .net v100.

```
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("customCookie", cred.Token);             
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new    {
                                                                            token = cred.Token,
                                                                            expires = cred.ExpirationDate
                                                                        });
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");            
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
        return response;
```

Now when I try to retrieve that cookie later on in subsequent requests using below I get null.

```
CookieHeaderValue cookie = context.Request.Headers.GetCookies("customCookie").FirstOrDefault();
```

I am wondering if there is another way to get the cookie which I set back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using v100?

If yes, you can try the following code:

```
        ArcGISHttpClientHandler.HttpRequestBegin += (sender, request) =>
        {
            var cookieContainer = ((System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler)sender).CookieContainer;
            var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(request.RequestUri);
            var customCookie = new Cookie("customCookie", "someValue") { Domain = request.RequestUri.Host };
            bool foundCookie = false;
            foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
            {
                if (cookie.Name == customCookie.Name)
                {
                    foundCookie = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!foundCookie)
                cookieContainer.Add(customCookie);

        };
```

ArcGISHttpClientHandler has an event HttpRequestBegin which is invoked on every request. You can use CookieContainer.GetCookies and Add to retrieve/add cookies.

Comment: Yes, I am using v100.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This seems to work but I have a doubt. How would I add this to my response object?

Comment: You can only add headers to the outgoing request at this point. Perhaps you can share a little more details about what you're trying to accomplish?